# Detect high amplitudes in a plot

Tags: python, algorithm, search, statistics, plot

I plotted a couple of values, that represent a signal strength being weak or high. My problem is, that I want to statistically evaluate the start and end X-coordinate.

[image: I channel vs. Samples axis]

My issue with that is, that these high-valued blue amplitudes within do have little sections where the Y coordinate is low (if I zoom). So using an average value across 10-20 samples isn't going to be helpful or exact. I'm not sure which algorithm makes sense here. Visually I just want the start and the end value of the black line.

Is there some smart way to get that? The values are within a CSV:

```
-0.00048828
0.00006104
-0.00024414
-0.00039673
-0.00109863
0.00286865
0.00527954
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try to filter the signal with something  like this:

signal: s[i]

filtered signal : f[i]

decrease coeff : c (choose a value between 0 and 1)

f[0] = s[0]

f[i] = max(c * f[i-1], s[i])

This method will introduce a bias on the end of high-amplitude areas. You will have to tune c to get the result with the expected precision. If c is too low: you will be too sensitive to high frequencies, and you will obtain unwanted "holes". If c is too high, the decrease of the filtered signal after a high amplitude area will be too slow.

Apply a threshold on the filtered signal to get the limits.

Comment: You have to define your problem clearly: how are defined X_start and X_end? As I understand your question, they are defined by the level of the envelop of your signal. If so, you have to filter your signal to get its envelop (using the algorithm in my answer for exemple), then apply a threshold on this envelop to detect the areas where you consider it high or low. When you have this segmentation done, you can easily compute X_start and X_end.